# List the relevant month title only once in an events lister

Tags: php, mysql

Can I list the month name only once per listing of that month and display remaining rows of events showing only the day word and date numeral, as listed below

Sat 13th Jul --- Event 1
Sun 14th ------- Event 2
Mon 15th ------- Event 3
Thurs 1st Aug--Event 4

My code so far:

```
$start_date = "STR_TO_DATE(field_2,'%m %d %Y') AS startDate,   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(field_2,'%m %d %Y'),'%a %D %b') AS startDate";  
$query= "SELECT * ,$start_date FROM events ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(field_2,'%m %d %Y') ASC ";  
$result = mysql_query($query);  
if (!$result) {  
    die(mysql_error());  
}  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    echo $row['startDate']; // event date  
    echo"&nbsp;-&nbsp;";  
    echo $row['field_1]; // venue   
    echo"<br />";  
}
```

Comment: Just add another argument to your loop that says 'when this month is the same as the last month, don't print the month'.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, I understand I can add an IF argument but I get stuck on how to work with a date that I stored in mysql text field for ease of use with cal datepicker. I assume I will have to do some date converting before I can loop through dates until month end.

Comment: Sorry guys, I changed the question but unsure of what is further expected of me as my query is still on hold, can you advise please.

Comment: Take a look at PHP functions [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thanks koala_dev I will look into those functions :-)